# Different output when Exception Handling Java code is run multiple times

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am aware that many questions about try-catch-finally blocks have been asked in this site. But I have a different doubt. I get different outputs when the code below is run multiple times.

I have a very simple class as follows:

Practice.java

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String []args) {
         System.out.println(getInteger());
    }

    public static int getInteger() {
       try {
           System.out.println("Try");
           throwException();
           return 1;
       } catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Catch Exception");
           e.printStackTrace();
           return 2;
       } finally {
            System.out.println("Finally");
      }
    }

   private static void throwException() throws Exception {
       throw new Exception("my exception");
   }
}
```

The output when I first run the code above is as follows:

```
Try
Catch Exception
Finally
2
java.lang.Exception: my exception
    at exceptionHandling.Practice.throwException(Practice.java:22)
    at exceptionHandling.Practice.getInteger(Practice.java:10)
    at exceptionHandling.Practice.main(Practice.java:4)
```

A different output when I run the code again is given below:

```
Try
Catch Exception
java.lang.Exception: my exception
    at exceptionHandling.Practice.throwException(Practice.java:22)
    at exceptionHandling.Practice.getInteger(Practice.java:10)
    at exceptionHandling.Practice.main(Practice.java:4)
Finally
2
```

Can somebody please explain such output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use different filehandles. Your output goes to `System.out`, `e.printStackTrace();` writes to `System.err` which will flush on different times.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this. I wanted to find the sequence of execution